# Filler plate alternatives? Welding an electrical panel twistout?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I don't have enough clearance to install a filler plate because of a power meter for load shedding EVSE that touches the electrical panel cover. See photos. What other options do I have? Is welding a previously removed twistout an option?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update 1:** Since I was asked, here are photos of the meter and the EVSE:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update 2:** I moved the meter in a small compartment at the top left, mounted it on a stick-on DIN rail and now I was able to properly put a filler plate. See photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147039/discussion-on-question-by-user162793-filler-plate-alternatives-welding-an-elect); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This probably should be rearranged to begin with

Right now, with the power meter just stuffed in there, not only are you dealing with something that could be cited as not "neat and workmanlike", you have no way of guaranteeing the ¼" separation required by NEC 725.136(D)(2) point a in this scenario:

> (D) Associated Systems Within Enclosures
>
> Class 2 and Class 3 circuit conductors in compartments, enclosures, device boxes, outlet boxes, or similar fittings shall be permitted to be installed with electric light, power, Class 1, non—power-limited fire alarm, and medium-power network-powered broadband communications circuits where they are introduced solely to connect the equipment connected to Class 2 and Class 3 circuits, and where (1) or (2) applies:
>
> 1. The electric light, power, Class 1, non—power-limited fire alarm, and medium-power network-powered broadband communications circuit conductors are routed to maintain a minimum of 6 mm (0.25 in.) separation from the conductors and cables of Class 2 and Class 3 circuits.
> 2. The circuit conductors operate at 150 volts or less to ground and also comply with one of the following:
>
> a. The Class 2 and Class 3 circuits are installed using Type CL3, CL3R, or CL3P or permitted substitute cables, provided these Class 3 cable conductors extending beyond the jacket are separated by a minimum of 6 mm (0.25 in.) or by a nonconductive sleeve or nonconductive barrier from all other conductors.
>
> b. The Class 2 and Class 3 circuit conductors are installed as a Class 1 circuit in accordance with 725.41.

So, I'd get some stick-on DIN rail (Hoffman ADIN3PA42) and use that to mount the meter so that the "bottom" (low-voltage end) is on the *left*, then use wire-ties to bundle/arrange things so that the required clearances are guaranteed (this may require disconnecting and reconnecting circuits from their breakers in order to reroute them).  The good news, at least, is that your cable is fine as NEC Table 725.154(A) lists CMR as a permitted substitute for CL3R.

This should also let you snap a filler plate into the hole.  If you still can't for some reason, taking the cover off and spot-welding the twistout back into place will work, as long as you can neatly weld sheet metal, of course.

Comment: There is not enough space to mount the power meter at the bottom of the panel. Right now is on top of a breaker slot. To meet the "neat and workmanlike" I can move it in the small compartment on top of the utility meter. It's not visible in the photo but there is a big compartment on the left of one of the visible CT clamps. I was initially planning on having it there but I had to put one of the CT clamps there and the other CT clamp is now on the way. If I arrange it a bit better I can make it work.

Comment: Code says: "separated by a minimum of 6 mm (0.25 in.) or by a nonconductive sleeve or nonconductive barrier from all other conductors" What's the definition of nonconductive sleeve or barrier here? Does the blue sleeve of the cable satisfy that? It's going to be hard to enforce the ¼" separation if I move the meter in the compartment I described earlier. So is there any appropriate sleeve to use instead? Does this separation also apply for the knockout? I don't think there are any knockouts left to have the ethernet cable on its own. Does it also apply on the EVSE unit (see new photo)?

Comment: @user162793 the requirement for separation or sleeving only applies to conductors extending beyond the cable jacket, so you're good there, but you do need to make sure the EVSE obeys it as well (should not be hard)

Comment: @user162793 -- however, putting it in a utility-side compartment will likely cause your utility to yell at you, so that's not an option.  You may have to mount it vertically in the panel's wiring gutter instead if that's possible, or on its side, mounted to the meter-main's compartment divider, for that matter

Comment: The small compartment, which is big enough to fit the power meter and even the CT clamps is on top of the utility meter but is accessible from my side. Imagine a square right above the circular utility meter with access from the right side. It's hard to see from the photo but I had to bend the wires a bit inside that compartment and one of the CT clamps is inside that compartment. It's completely isolated from the utility-side, which I don't have access anyway, so I don't expect any issues.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood, I only need to worry about the ¼" separation for the tiny part the conductors are not insulated with the blue cable jacket right? Not sure if you noticed, I've updated my question with a photo of my wiring on the EVSE side. In my opinion, my current wiring on both ends meets NEC 725.136(D)(2). But I do agree I might not get a pass for "neat and workmanlike" so I'll try to move the meter somewhere better.

Comment: By the way, are the wires for the CT clamps considered class 2 which means they also require ¼" separation? If yes, then the best place of having the meter is in that compartment since they can be completely separated and out of the way from all the other power wires.

Comment: @user162793 -- that's a good question re: the CT clamp wiring -- you'd probably need to poke Carlo Gavazzi if it's not in the power meter's manual.  You are correct about the quarter-inch separation, and it sounds like that small compartment will work for the power meter, as well

Comment: Is the STEGO 09510.0-01 equivalent to the Hoffman ADIN3PA42 you suggested? It's half the price.

Comment: @user162793 -- it looks to be a suitable substitute, yeah

Comment: Thanks! One more question. The power meter is 2.1 inches wide. Do you recommend mounting it on a 2 or 3 inches DIN rail?

Comment: @user162793 the stick-on DIN rails should provide enough for the meter's clip to grab onto, so its OK if the rail is a bit short on the ends

Comment: The stick-on DIN rail arrived and I mounted the meter in that small compartment. I updated my question with 4 photos of my final solution. Only thing left is to label the breakers before the inspection. Thanks for your help. Please let me know if you notice any violations.